How to properly quantize model with quanto?
I am trying to quantize Qwen model, but it seems to be not working.
This is my snippet in Google Colab (runtime-> free T4 GPU):
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM
from optimum.quanto import QuantizedModelForCausalLM, qint8

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained('Qwen/Qwen2-0.5B-Instruct')
qmodel = QuantizedModelForCausalLM.quantize(model, weights=qint8)

foot = model.get_memory_footprint()
print(f'{foot / 1_000_000_000} GB')

qfoot = qmodel.get_memory_footprint()
print(f'{qfoot / 1_000_000_000} GB')

Output:
2.923327304 GB
2.923327304 GB

Despite same memory footprint, when I called model.named_parameters(), it showed float32 types for both model and qmodel. I am not getting any errors.

You print foot in the second print again, not qfoot

My bad, but it was only typo in the post, on Colab I have qfoot, and values are still the same.

Why are you specifically using quanto? Is it known to work well with Qwen models?

No specific reason, I thought quanto is good choice for float32 based LLMs

try this way
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("Qwen/Qwen2-0.5B")
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("Qwen/Qwen2-0.5B")

def compute_module_sizes(model):
    """
    Compute the size of each submodule of a given model.
    """
    from collections import defaultdict
    module_sizes = defaultdict(int)
    for name, tensor in named_module_tensors(model, recurse=True):
      size = tensor.numel() * dtype_byte_size(tensor.dtype)
      name_parts = name.split(".")
      for idx in range(len(name_parts) + 1):
        module_sizes[".".join(name_parts[:idx])] += size

    return module_sizes

module_sizes = compute_module_sizes(model)
print(f"The model size is {module_sizes[''] * 1e-9} GB")

it will be The model size is 3.58674688 GB
if you use
from quanto import quantize, freeze

quantize(model, weights=torch.int8, activations=None)
freeze(model)

it will be The model size is 2.651227464 GB

You haven't defined compute_module_sizes function

oh yes thank you it fixed. use this link https://blog.gopenai.com/linear-quantization-with-hugging-face-quanto-222a1d29721f
